# Combine two queries into one with IN different condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select

If divided into two queries, we get the correct result.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE field_1 = 'name_1' AND (field_2) IN ('123', '456', '345');

SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE field_1 = 'name_2' AND (field_2) IN ('456', '876', '548', '111');
```

But how can combine these two queries into one. It is possible that there will be more than two requests.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: What is the "correct" result?  What is the data?

Comment: `OR` the two WHERE clause conditions-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you us OR in your WHERE clause you can do this in one query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE 
(col1 = 'name_1' AND col2 IN ('123', '456', '345')
OR 
(col1 = 'name_2' AND col2 IN ('456', '876', '548', '111')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use OR :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE (field_1 = 'name_1' AND (field_2) IN ('123', '456', '345'))
OR ( field_1 = 'name_2' AND (field_2) IN ('456', '876', '548', '111'));
```

Answer (score 1):

U can achieve with below  method.

Method 1:

```
  SELECT field_1 ,field_2 FROM table_name
  WHERE  (field_1 = 'name_1' AND (field_2) IN ('123', '456', '345')
         ) OR 
         (
          field_1 = 'name_2' AND (field_2) IN ('456', '876', '548','111')
         )
```

Method2:

```
SELECT field_1 ,field_2 FROM table_name
WHERE  (field_1 = 'name_1' AND  (field_2) IN ('123', '456', '345')         
UNION              
SELECT field_1 ,field_2 FROM table_name

WHERE field_1 = 'name_2' AND (field_2) IN ('456', '876','548','111')
```

Answer (score 0):

### If you are in need of the output anyway.

**Put UNION between the queries then**